# Team foundation client 2010 and server 2008

Tags: tfs

Can I use TFS Client 2010 with TFS server 2008?

Or it is not recommended ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We seem to be doing OK with this exact setup. All of the team queries, documents, reports, builds and source control integration seem to be working just fine. Admittedly, we've only been in the 2010 environment (against TFS2008) for about a week now.

That said, I imagine if we were going to run into issues, we would have by now.

Comment: Did you have to convert your 2008 project into 2010 to make it work ?

Comment: Yes, we had to convert existing projects, which we'll be doing on an as-needed basis. (We still have VS2005 and 2008 as well.) And new 2010 projects worked out of box.